# Most efficient way to filter a large dataframe based on percentiles

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a large dataframe, about 5 million rows and 200 columns. I am running the code below to filter out based on percentiles and data types

## Code below

```
col_percentile_filter = 0.98
modeldata_revised_2 = modeldata.loc[:, (modeldata.dtypes!='object') & (modeldata.quantile(col_percentile_filter) >= 1) & (modeldata.min() != modeldata.max())]
```

The code currently takes a lot of time to run. What is a more efficient way to run this?

Comment: would be great if you can revisit your recently asked questions and accept/vote up respective answers. otherwise - why we should answer :o)

Answer (score 1):

When you're running

`modeldata_revised_2 = modeldata.loc[:, (modeldata.dtypes!='object') & (modeldata.quantile(col_percentile_filter) >= 1) & (modeldata.min() != modeldata.max())]`

You're pretty much computing 3 different dataframes then finding the intersection between them. [df.query()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) is much better for this kind of thing, something like this:

```
model_min = modeldata.min()
model_max = modeldata.max()
modeldata_revised_2 = modeldata.query("dtypes!='object' & quantile(col_percentile_filter) >= 1 & @model_min != @model_max")
```

A more comprehensive explanation I found is at:
https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/03.12-performance-eval-and-query.html

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I got an error saying dtypes is not defined

UndefinedVariableError: name 'dtypes' is not defined